# How to make a button make visible objects in another UserForm?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to make a UserForm containing multiple labels and textboxs that are set to visible=false and that only when the user select from another UserForm it shows the labels and textboxs that I want

THE FIRST USERFORM (Main)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

If ComboBox1 = "Test1" Then
Test.Show
 --------------------
ElseIf ComboBox1 = "Test2" Then
Test.Show
 --------------------
Else
MsgBox "Select an option"

End If


End Sub
```

---

THE SECOND USEFORM (Test)

Contains label1 and label2, if ComboBox1 from Main = "Test1" I want label1 to be visible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably do this with a property on the second form

form 1 might look like this

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    test.textInForm1ComboBox1 = Me.ComboBox1.Text
End Sub
```

and form 2 might look like this

```
Public Property Let textInForm1ComboBox1 (boxValue as String)
    Select Case boxValue
        Case "Test 1"
            Me.Label1.Visible = True
        Case "Test 2"
            Me.Label2.Visible = True
        Case Else
           MsgBox "Select an option"
      End select
End Property
```

Comment: That's a bit presumptuous don't you think?  Do you presume I don't use `Option Explicit` or that it is not followed by `Private test as testUserForm`? Is it possible that `Set test = New testUserForm` is executed when form 1 is initialized?  The default instance could be `OnomatopoeiaFlipFlapFlarpityFloop` or `test` or `UserForm1`.  A negative does not prove a positive.   What we know, is that `Me` supports encapsulation and `test` can be scoped to global, module, or both and that it is possibly a default instance.

Comment: I feel like I have to call out that `MsgBox`.  I can understand why you omitted it from your answers.  Personally, I have no idea what purpose it serves but I can easily argue that the OP may be using the modal window as a break point to pause program execution. In such an event, my answer continues to works flawlessly while all three of yours break the project.  And no, I use `test` as the name of the variable holding the user form.  It is not declared anywhere in any example.  Do not presume what cannot be known.